# Aliases in non-interactive bash

Tags: bash, alias

I would like to get aliases to work in non-interactive bash. I run the following command :

```
bash -c "alias toto=ls; shopt -s expand_aliases; alias toto=ls; toto"
```

and I get the following :

```
bash: toto : commande not found
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [bash: unable to set and use alias in the same line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38526612/3776858)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `man bash`:

> Aliases are expanded when a command is
>          read, not when it is executed.  Therefore, an alias definition
>          appearing on the same line as another command does not take
>          effect until the next line of input is read.

That means, even in an interactive shell,

```
alias toto=ls; toto
```

wouldn't work. There must be a line break between alias definition and call. So,

```
bash -c 'shopt -s expand_aliases; alias toto=ls
toto'
```

should work.