# Unable to execute bashrc function using ANSIBLE

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to execute a bashrc function "enableSsh" using ANSIBLE. I am using below ANSIBLE code to get this done but getting error: enableSsh command not found.

```
- name: Switch to user root and enable ssh
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
  shell: . .bashrc && enableSsh
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
```

**Note:** I tested it removing enableSsh and reloading bashrc is working fine. enableSsh is a function defined in remote server's bashrc file and works fine if execute directly from command line.

Comment: Try to specify the complete path to the file you want to source. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27541856/1137055).

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/c6c0e27a60c2a3ea1e430353153f19a3

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with Ansible, this is a shortcoming of the alias command as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38526612/bash-unable-to-set-and-use-alias-in-the-same-line).

Comment: @Zeitounator OP did say that but I don't think it's out of question that he meant aliases since I can't reproduce the problem with functions either. On that note, his input would be welcome.